# Why does the angle for maximum range decrease in the presence of drag?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

In the absence of drag, the angle to launch a projectile is 45°. In the presence of drag, the angle to attain max range is complicated. However, there seems to be consensus that it has to be less than 45° but I can't figure out why.

Say we launch slightly below 45°, wouldn't the drag cause the horizontal component of the velocity to decelerate more quickly? Furthermore, we are decreasing the air time of the projectile so why would it give a longer range? Without going into too much math or appealing to simulation, is there any way to intuit an explanation behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the presence of drag, the angle for maximum range is typically less than 45 degrees. When an object is launched at an angle less than 45 degrees, it has a higher horizontal velocity component, which helps counteract the decelerating effect of drag. As a result, the object can travel farther before hitting the ground.

At angles greater than 45 degrees, the vertical component of the object's velocity becomes more significant, causing it to spend more time in the air. However, the drag force acting opposite to the direction of motion slows the object down more rapidly, reducing its overall range.

Therefore, to achieve maximum range in the presence of drag, it is generally advisable to launch the object at an angle less than 45 degrees.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate a little more on how to come to the conclusion that the higher horizontal velocity component is more significant that the increase in the decelerating effect of drag when <45°? Also, in the case of >45°, what do you mean by "slow the object down more rapidly"? Is this in the vertical or horizontal component? Thank you.

Comment: When the object is launched at an angle <45°, the horizontal component of velocity is higher compared to launching at angles >45°. The higher horizontal velocity helps counteract the decelerating effect of drag acting in the opposite direction. In this case, the horizontal velocity component plays a dominant role in determining the object's range because it contributes to the forward motion and helps overcome the drag force more effectively.

Comment: The combined effect of the drag force on both the horizontal and vertical components of velocity leads to a faster decrease in the object's overall speed. As a result, the object's range is reduced because it loses speed more quickly and covers a shorter distance before hitting the ground.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum range without drag is achieve if the angle to launch a projectile is 45°  , this is also true with drag

**Simulation**

[image]

---

The equations

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}x \left( \tau \right) +{\frac {{\it Cw}\,
\sqrt { \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}x \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}+
 \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}y \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}}{\frac {
d}{d\tau}}x \left( \tau \right) }{m}}=0\\
{\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}y \left( \tau \right) +{\frac {mg+{\it Cw}
\,\sqrt { \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}x \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}
+ \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}y \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}}{\frac 
{d}{d\tau}}y \left( \tau \right) }{m}}=0
$$